# Flutter oddly not reloading widget

Tags: flutter, dart

I have been working with flutter just a while now but I have never experienced such a weird problem. basically I'm checking if there is a logged on username show them the main page and if not show them the signup page. after the user signs up (and logs in at the same time) I want to take him to my main page. even though I return a new Scaffold the mobile screen doesn't change at all. not with a hot load or anything. but after stopping the program and running it again (because the user is logged in) it automatically goes to my main page (which I want to do without having to stop the program and running it again. any ideas why this is happening couldn't find anything related to this.

[image]

```
import 'package:sociagrowapp/models/user.dart';
import 'package:sociagrowapp/Authenticate/SignIn.dart';
import 'package:sociagrowapp/HomePages/Home.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class Wrapper extends StatefulWidget{
  @override
  createState() => _Wrapper();
}

class _Wrapper extends State<Wrapper> {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    print(user);

    // return either the Home or Authenticate widget
    if (user == null){
      print('Should Changed 3');
      return Scaffold(
       body: SignIn()
      );
    }
    else {
      print('Should Changed');
      print('Should Changed2');

      return PageData()

    }

  }
}
```

Just in case I will add the PagesData Code but I don't think it is related to that.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:sociagrowapp/services/auth.dart';

int selectedbotnavi = 0;

class DailyTasks extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  createState() => _DailyTasks();
}

class _DailyTasks extends State<DailyTasks>
{
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Center(
        child: Text("15")
    );
  }
}

class Settings extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  createState() => _Settings();
}

class _Settings extends State<Settings>
{

  String _httpdataretrieved;



  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  {
    return Column(
      children: <Widget>[
        Container(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Text('Your Account Username',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400),),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 20, 0, 0),
        ),
        Container(width:MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
          child: Text('  Important: Your Account must be public for SociaGrow. \n There are limited Features available to private Accounts',style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w900,fontSize:14),
          ),
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 5, 0, 20),
        ),

        Container(child: TextField(
          obscureText: true,
          decoration: InputDecoration(
            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
            labelText: 'Username',

          ),
        ),
          width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.8,
          alignment: Alignment.center,
          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 0, 0, 15),
        ),
        Container(
          child: RaisedButton(


            child: Text('Change Username'),
          ),

        )

      ],



    );
  }
}

List <Widget> Pages = [new DailyTasks(),new DailyTasks(),new DailyTasks()];

class PageData extends StatefulWidget
{
  @override
  createState() => _PageData();
}

class _PageData extends State<PageData>
{
  void _changeselectbotnaviindex(int index)
  {
    selectedbotnavi = index;
    setState(() {
    });
  }

  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)
  { 

    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: Container(
          child: Image.asset('assets/Logo.png',width: 100,height: 200,),
          padding: EdgeInsetsDirectional.fromSTEB(0, 10, 0  , 0),

        ),
        actions: <Widget>[
          FlatButton(
            child: Text('Sign out'),
            onPressed:  () async {
              await this._auth.signOut();
            },
          ),
        ],
        ),

        body: Pages[selectedbotnavi],
        bottomNavigationBar: BottomNavigationBar(
          type: BottomNavigationBarType.fixed,
          items :[
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.timelapse),title:Text('Daily Tasks')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.call_made),title:Text('Growth')),
            BottomNavigationBarItem(icon: Icon(Icons.settings),title:Text('Settings')),],
          currentIndex: selectedbotnavi,
          onTap: _changeselectbotnaviindex,
          selectedItemColor: Colors.amber[800],
          unselectedItemColor: Colors.black,
          showUnselectedLabels: true,
        )
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is not the way you navigate to a new page in Flutter.

In Flutter, the way to navigate between pages is with [Navigator](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Navigator-class.html), which is a widget that manages a set of child widgets with a stack discipline. That is, `Navigator` has everything ready for you to navigate between pages easily. When you create an app with `MaterialApp`, Flutter attaches a `Navigator` to the top of the widget tree for you under the hood. This way, you can access the `Navigator` in your widget tree via `context`, by calling `Navigator.of(context)`.

In your case, when the user taps the sign up button in your sign up page, you should do something like:

```dart
Navigator.of(context).pushReplacement(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => PageData()));
```

This way, your app will navigate to `PageData` when the user signs in.

Check out this [Flutter.dev article on navigating pages](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/navigation-basics) for more details on the topic.

Comment: I do understand the navigation in Flutter. the main reason that I don't use page navigation is that when my users click on the signup button there are many things that could go wrong. just like when sign out does. and because I want to do things like reauthentication I need to have a wrapper that constantly checks if the user is logged in or not. My main question though is that why isn't the PageData section loading (It even goes into the function and returns the new page) but no change in the application screen.

Comment: I think it is not good practice to navigate to another screen by changing the build return in a state when you can navigate with `Navigator` only if all those conditions you need to check are satisfied.

Still, let's try to do it the way you want. Can you share how are you updating your `Wrapper` state? Are you calling `setState` in your sing up page or updating the `Provider` somehow?

Answer (score 0):

You have to call SetState() so your build method is called again.

You could add a VoidListener to your SignIn(onLogin:(){setState(() {});})